# please correct my code, its just not working, MPG calculator

Tags: c#, forms, textbox

here is the code, please help. Its not working. I was promised it would. 
I cant convert the string of the text box to an int so i cant do the math required.

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int userVal = int.Parse(Form1.textBox1.Text);
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int answer = (Form1.textBox1 * Form1.textBox2);
            MessageBox.Show("MPG: ", answer);
        }
```

Comment: You are not using userVal

Comment: Try using int.TryParse instead of int.Parse. Of course that's not the only problem with this code.

Comment: 1) `int userVal = int.Parse(Form1.textBox1.Text);` you cannot run this code outside of a method or constructor. 2) why da hack is your `textBox1` static? if it is not then remove the `Form1`! 3) `Its not working.` this is the worse problem description you can give! Do you have compilation errors? runtime errors? exceptions ? tell us more....

Answer (score 1):

First of all. You should really start at the basics, because in your code you try to multiply two `TextBox` controls which isn't possible.

Secondly. I corrected your code.

`Int32.TryParse(someString,out anInt)` tries to convert the first parameter(someString) to an `Int32` and returns a boolean value about the conversion whether it was successful or not. If the conversion was successful the converted value is stored in the second parameter(anInt) and `Int32.TryParse(someString,out anInt)` returns `true`.

In the corrected code you simply try to convert the `string`s from both `TextBox`es. If you were able to do so (return value of `Int32.TryParse`) simply multiply both `int`s you got from `Int32.TryParse`

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num1,num2;
    If(Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out num1) && Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text,out num2))
    {
        int answer = num1 * num2;
        string output = "MPG: "+ answer.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(output);
    }

}
```

Comment: @MongZhu thank you for your feedback. Edited my answer again explaining how the code works.

Answer (score -2):

```
int userVal = int.Parse(Form1.textBox1.Text);
```

First of all, this line must be placed in the button1_Click function in order to work. But now the issue is that you're using a string input to accept numbers, which is not a good idea because if you type "abc" for example, int.Parse will throw an exception.

Now you just have to replace textBox1 and 2 to numerical inputs, and then use this code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int answer = (numericalInput1.value * numbericalInput2.value);
    MessageBox.Show("MPG: ", answer);
}
```

Comment: This will crash in any case. What is Form1? It is the class name and in C# we don't have automatic form instances. You need an instance of Form1. Second what is the content of the two textboxes. Int.Parse will fail if the content is not convertible to integers. For example an empty string

Comment: 1. He simply didn't include public partial class Form1 : Form. Also he's probably using VisualStudio Form WYSIWYG editor, which handles the Form instance. 2. I agree, he should use the numeric input that I forgot the name, NumericUpDownVal or something.

Comment: @Laurent If you want to access an element inside a class use the `this` keyword, but in most cases it isn't necessary.

Comment: Yep I didn't notice he did that @schgab. By the way I edited my answer.